# Netsuite Parent Child Relationships and Inline editting

Tags: netsuite

So I have to model a many-to-many relationship in Netsuite.  This is between Customers and Pricing Exceptions.

So first I create a list for the list of Exception types
Then I create a custom record that has two List/Record Lookups one against Client (our renamed Customer), and the other to the list/record for our Billing Exceptions.

I mark the first one (against client) as the Parent Record, and I enable Inline editing for the new record type.
!http://www.cryptoknight.org/img/4_8_2016_10_44_18_AM.png

Finally I move the new list from the custom tab to a specific tab called Support Fee Increase.

At this point, I open up a client/customer and expect a typical Netsuite Inline editing box.  Which I don't see, I can click the button to make a new exception, and it launches the small pop-up form up, but it doesn't allow me to do this inline.

Obviously I missed something, but what?

Comment: Added links to what I see (link 1) and what I would expect (link 2).

http://www.cryptoknight.org/img/4_8_2016_10_45_38_AM.png

http://www.cryptoknight.org/img/4_8_2016_10_49_19_AM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for child record editing.

Try checking the `Allow Child Record Editting` checkbox on the child record type.  (It doesn't make any more sense, but the helptext for the field *tries* to clarify:

> Check this box to allow records of this type to be edited directly when they display as children in a sublist on a parent record.
>
> Child records are never editable in parent records that have more than 10,000 child record lines, even when the Allow Child Record Editing option is enabled for the record type.
>
> Note: This option was formerly labeled Allow Inline Editing. Its label was changed because it is not related to the Inline Editing feature or to the Inline Editing switch that displays on list pages when that feature is enabled. The name change also was intended to avoid confusion with the Enable Inline Editing option.

Comment: Same effect... I turned the "Allow Child Record Editing" On, and allowed deletes, and it still doesn't let me perform the function without the pop-up window.

Comment: It must have been a combination... something I did and then that... but now it works... I was expecting it to work when not in edit mode... heh.  Thanks!